# Move scheduled tasks to a new folder?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

In the windows task management I created a new folder, lets call it "mytasks".

I expected to be able to organize new tasks into it by using drag&drop from existing tasks, but somehow that's not possible.

How do I move already existing tasks to a new folder/category?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Actually it is not possible to drag and drop a task to a new folder or just simply move from one folder to another. You will need to create a new task on that folder.

If you want to "move" all your tasks to your custom folder you can import the existing tasks directly from the XMLs stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Right-click the new destination folder and select **Import Task…**
3. Browse to: `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`
4. Change the file type at the bottom from XML files (*.xml) to All files (*.*)
5. A list of all existing tasks and folders will be listed, select the task to be moved and click **Open**
6. The task will now be imported into the new location but will also still exist at the original location, so right-click on the original task and select **Delete**

Reference: https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/move-windows-tasks-in-task-scheduler/

Comment: Thank you, I really would have expected a better usability in that case \:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795560/schtasks-exe-to-create-a-task-folder combined with a little powershell scripting should help.

Comment: How utterly bizarre!

Comment: would it work to just move the file to the folder?

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to 'transfer' the tasks from one folder to another.
It's a bit cumbersome but here are the steps:

Step 1: Export the task (one by one) by right clicking on the task and select 'Export' which will then create a file in the selected folder.

Step 2: Import the (exported) task by right click on the new folder and select 'Import Task...'. Then select the file that you created during the export process.

This should work in any newer Windows versions.